In playwright using JS, need to add product to cart from list of product
I have a problem with this playwright script:
exports.ProductListing = class ProductListing {
  constructor(page) {
     this.page = page;
     this.productLocator = page.locator("xpath= 
                       (//*[@class='inventory_item'])");
     this.addToCartButton = page.getByRole("button", {name: "Add to cart"})
  }
        
  async addProductToCart(productName) {
     await this.productLocator
               .filter({ hasText: productName })
               .locator(await this.addToCartButton)
              .click();
   }
}

What is wrong with this code?, I'm getting the following timeout error everytime:
Test timeout of 90000ms exceeded.
Error: locator.click: Test timeout of 90000ms exceeded.
Call log:
  - waiting for locator('xpath=(//*[@class=\'inventory_item\'])').filter({ hasText: 'Sauce Labs Onesie' }).locator(getByRole('button', { name: 'Add to cart' }))

   at ..\Pages\productspage.js:13

  11 |                     .filter({ hasText: productName })
  12 |                     .locator(await this.addToCartButton)
> 13 |                     .click();
     |                      ^
  14 |             }
  15 |         }      


Please share the page you're testing and the full test code. See [mcve]. XPath is discouraged--use user-visible locators. Thanks.

Like ggorlen said. Don´t use xpath. You can use page.locator(".inventory_item") instead. I guess, how you determine your product and the way you filter it might be wrong. However, please share more information.
